# Missing file path

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I would like to send the image and text that I received from the user to the server but I have problems.

```
void sendData(final String username) {
    String url = "http://hesabdarbartar.ir/api/update";
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("data_user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    AndroidNetworking.upload(url)
      .addMultipartFile(Key.IMAGE, new File(path))
      .addMultipartParameter(Key.NAME, username)
      .addHeaders(Key.TOKEN, preferences.getString("api_token", ""))
      .build()
      .getAsObject(User.class, new ParsedRequestListener<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(User response) {
          try {
            preferences.edit().putString("name", response.getName()).apply();
            preferences.edit().putString("pic", response.getPic()).apply();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();

          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "خطا در ارتباط با سرور!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
          Log.i("ererer", "" + String.valueOf(anError));
        }
      });
  }



  void askReadPermission() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
      .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
      .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
          pickImage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

          if (response != null && response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
            Snackbar.make(btn_confirm, "برای انتخاب فایل دسترسی ضروری است!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("اجازه دادن!", new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), null));
                startActivity(i);
              }
            }).show();
          } else {
            Snackbar.make(btn_confirm, "برای انتخاب فایل دسترسی ضروری است!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

        }
      }).check();
  }

  private void pickImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
      path = data.getData().getPath();
      btn_confirm.setEnabled(true);
      img_prof.setImageURI(data.getData());
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a snapshot of the program's problems

[image]

Comment: Post errors as text and not as images

Comment: You need to write your image to cache before upload and then give path.

Comment: Please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you receive in `onActivityResult()` is an `Uri` of the image, not its real path. You should convert it to the real path, then you can use it in `new File(path)`. [There is](https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626) a converter:

```
public class RealPathUtil {

    public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
        else {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
        }
        return realPath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = 0;
        String result = "";
        if (cursor != null) {
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

}
```